# How can I find out the relative order of various symbols in a MySQL character set collation (e..g utf8_unicode_ci)?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

I'm trying to find a chart or something that shows the collation order of, e.g. '_' vs '0', but so far no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual says

MySQL implements the xxx_unicode_ci collations according to the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) described at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/. The collation uses the version-4.0.0 UCA weight keys: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt. Currently, the xxx_unicode_ci collations have only partial support for the Unicode Collation Algorithm. [...]

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html